# Differentiating between edited and selected in editable QComboBox

Tags: qt

I have an editable QComboBox. I add some items to it with associated user data.

```
QComboBox *myCB = new QComboBox;
myCB->setEditable(true);
myCB->addItem("Item1", "1");
myCB->addItem("Item2", "2");
myCB->addItem("Item3", "3");
```

When an item is selected from the combo box, I want to get its associated user data
But user types in something into the combo box, I just want to get the typed string.

```
if (selected_from_combobox)
   return myCB->itemData(myCB->currentIndex()).toString();
else if (typed_by_user)
   return myCB->currentText();
```

How do I differentiate between 2 cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use 2 signals like this:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QComboBox *myCB = new QComboBox(this);
    myCB->setEditable(true);
    myCB->addItem("Item1", "1");
    myCB->addItem("Item2", "2");
    myCB->addItem("Item3", "3");
    connect(myCB,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),this,SLOT(indexChanged(int)));
    connect(myCB,SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(textChanged(QString)));
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem but I'm using Qt 4.8, so there is no signal currentTextChanged. Do you have any idea, to solve it.

Comment: Sven, I do not have 4.8 so I cannot test it before, but I see from docs that you have 2 signals currentIndexChanged one with parameter int and the second with a param QString so you can connect them to 2 different slots and it should work like the example above. If you open a new question I can also paste some code there